# Why do you prefer raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, rfid

I am looking for a computer to be placed inside a turnstile. Someone suggested to me that I can use raspberry pi. Yet, I don't have knowledge in it but it sounds interesting so I'd like to try. There are questions that bothers me.

In this world where Mac and Windows are (in my point of view) much more famous. Why would I choose raspberry pi which uses linux? It seems difficult to advertise a system that runs in linux right or is it?. Aside from that, it is also difficult to search for products that will be compatible with linux os, such as rfid readers or any other item. So what's good with raspberry?

Comment: Please avoid asking [open ended and opinion based questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/71336/edit) your question an be more specific. What kind of problem do you need to solve? What have you tried until now? Linux vs. Windows evangelization stuff is highly unfit for this kind of site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ~80% Marketshare

While Linux has a small market share on desktop computers, it is the dominant OS on IoT with ~80% as per this article:

http://www.businesskorea.co.kr/english/news/ict/18525-iot-operating-system-linux-takes-lead-iot-market-keeping-80-market-share

Linux has had a strong market share even before Raspberry PI. Think of all the small devices like smartphones (Android uses a Linux kernel) and routers.

## Reputation

Linux has a very good reputation since years. It is backed and used by big organizations like IBM, Amazon Web Services, Cisco, Dell, Facebook, Fujitsu, Google, IBM, Intel, Microsoft, NetApp, Rackspace, VMware ... the list goes on and on. They support it to use it mainly on their servers and to provide services for other enterprises who themselves run mission-critical services under Linux:

https://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/announcements/2014/04/amazon-web-services-cisco-dell-facebook-fujitsu-google-ibm-intel

## Supported Raspberry PI Hardware

I have yet to see a piece of hardware sold to work with a Raspberry PI that **doesn't** work either out of the box with Linux or isn't shipped with drivers. There are tons of RFID readers for Raspberry PI.

Comment: Add supercomputer, of the top 500 supercomputer is 99.6% using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is a common OS in the IT industry. It is driving the most super computers in the world, and is a common OS in the IoT market. Linux powers many of the biggest Internet properties (e.g., Google, Amazon, Facebook, eBay, Twitter and Yahoo!)

It is estimated it will have about 5% of the total IT market in 2017.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_adoption